# Area 51 Bug: Question appears on wrong proposal

Tags: bug, area-51

On the proposal page for [3D Printing and Rapid Prototyping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing-and-rapid-prototyping), one of the two discussions (questions) listed is [Ideas for Super User em Português](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/ideas-for-super-user-em-portugu%C3%AAs).

This discussion clearly has nothing to do with 3D printing & prototyping. The discussion also has a lot of views and upvotes, which means it's getting lots of traffic and it's a good discussion. It's just appearing somewhere other than where it belongs. I'm not sure *why* it's appearing on the 3D Printing proposal, but it's *also* appearing where it belongs, on the (closed) proposal for [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues).

Comment: It's because the [original version](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/posts/19807/revisions) actually linked all those proposals in the body, so all the proposals got linked to the question. I'm not sure if there's any way to remove that link from them all.

Comment: @animuson is correct, I noticed Robert tried to remove those links by deleting and undeleting, but even this didn't help. Guess it needs a dev power to manually remove those links.

Comment: Should the links appear due to a past version of a question or answer? I understand current version causing links, but if the current version doesn't have it, shouldn't the link/auto-mention go away?

Comment: Looks like someone called the cavalry, it's fixed now. Oh my, they simply deleted the whole proposal. Sledgehammer!